# Why HMS Push Kit onBackgroundRemoteMessageReceived() not triggering in background.js file

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, huawei-mobile-services

My Ionic capacitor is set as per these [instructions](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides/receiving-data-messages-at-app-killed-state-0000001058644809-V1). It is able to receive data messages just fine when the app is in the background or foreground. But the background.js script is not being called when the app is killed.

```
this.hmsPush.setBackgroundFile("public/assets/background.js")
```

background.js

```
var data = {
    "key":"value"
};

onGetItemResponse((result)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});

onBackgroundRemoteMessageReceived((remoteMessage)=>{
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(remoteMessage.data);
    const headlessNotification = {
                "title": "[Headless] " + jsonData.title,
                "message": jsonData.message.replace("{{name}}","YourName")
            };
    const notification = JSON.stringify(headlessNotification);
    HmsLocalNotification.backgroundLocalNotification(notification);
});

HmsPush.setItem("test",JSON.stringify(data));
HmsPush.getItem("test");
HmsPush.removeItem("test");
```

**Update 1**
Here is the log when I try to send and data message and the app is already killed.

This line is suspicious

```
04-25 10:20:01.809 W/ActivityManager( 1461): Service starting has been prevented by iaware or trustsbase sInfo ServiceInfo{8882f89 com.huawei.hms.cordova.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService}
```

```
04-25 10:20:01.776 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [SocketRead_09:20:20-233]enter cancelAlarm(Action=com.huawei.android.push.intent.RESPONSE_FAIL
04-25 10:20:01.778 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [SocketRead_09:20:20-233]process cmdid to receive from pushSrv:44, subCmdId:FF
04-25 10:20:01.783 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [SocketRead_09:20:20-233]dispatchIntent over
04-25 10:20:01.785 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]process push message cmdid from pushSrv:44, subCmdId:FF
04-25 10:20:01.796 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]msgType:3 [0:PassBy msg, 1:System notification, 2:normal notification, 3:HCM PassBy msg],userId:0
04-25 10:20:01.799 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209] closeTokenCheck: false
04-25 10:20:01.802 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]app declare HmsMessageService num is: 1
04-25 10:20:01.802 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]judge process is running start
04-25 10:20:01.805 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]no running process.
04-25 10:20:01.805 W/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]process  com.**** not exist and control 0
04-25 10:20:01.805 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]tempDozeWhileListTime = 10000
04-25 10:20:01.805 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]add com.**** to doze temp white list
04-25 10:20:01.807 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]do not need to apply net.
04-25 10:20:01.809 W/ActivityManager( 1461): Service starting has been prevented by iaware or trustsbase sInfo ServiceInfo{8882f89 com.huawei.hms.cordova.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService}
04-25 10:20:01.809 W/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]start remote message service failed
04-25 10:20:01.813 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]message 0A3680A0490F8108 is cached success: true
04-25 10:20:01.814 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]send passby message by start service for: com.****,msgID:0A3680A0490F8108
04-25 10:20:01.814 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]process cmdid to send to pushSrv:45, subCmdId:FF
04-25 10:20:01.815 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]send msg to remote srv success
04-25 10:20:01.815 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]handleMessageResponse the response msg is :45,msgId:0A3680A0490F8108,displayPkgName:com.****,flag:1B
04-25 10:20:01.815 I/PushLog110105309( 5138): [ReceiverDispatcher-209]enter AlarmTools:setInexactAlarm(intent:Intent { act=com.huawei.action.push.intent.CHECK_CHANNEL_CYCLE pkg=android } interval:1200000ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In killing state, can you find this information in log? " ** onMessageReceived ** "

You can use this command to catch log:
adb logcat -c && adb logcat -vtime > logcat1.txt

Comment: The "** onMessageReceived **" is not logged when the app is killed.
I have updated my question with the android log when the app is killed.
Look this line might be the culprit.
04-25 10:20:01.809 W/ActivityManager( 1461): Service starting has been prevented by iaware or trustsbase sInfo ServiceInfo{8882f89 com.huawei.hms.cordova.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService}
Thanks.

Comment: Which phone you used? Can you show the screenshot of "About Phone" page?

Comment: Its a Huawei Nova 9 with Harmony OS  China versión, I'm suspecting this is the root cause.

Comment: China Version... Yes, you are right. In China version, it is not allowed to start the background service except the app in the allowlist. It is better to use the phone out of China to test this function.

Comment: Confirmed this with Huawei support too.
Do you know to add apps into such allowlist?

Comment: If you just want to have a test on the phone, it is not suggested for special permission. Probably it will be rejected. But if your app is going to release in China region and it is necessary to receive data message, you can follow this guide:  https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050042183#section037425218509

Answer (score 0):

the log tells the root cause.
04-25 10:20:01.809 W/ActivityManager( 1461): Service starting has been prevented by iaware or trustsbase sInfo ServiceInfo{8882f89 com.huawei.hms.cordova.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService}

Solution is below. Just add a delay when starting

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext() ,ServiceName.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
},1000);
```

please refer to this url for more info: https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=01750-e3e353a0-ceec-4138-b2aa-0c221be37c13

Comment: Add to which file?